# How do I transfer nodes categorized with one taxonomy term to another?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Im on d7. I have a lot of nodes on my site that are all categorized with one of eight terms of my "category" vocabulary. I have been doing a theme redesign that calls for me to make a new taxonomy vocabulary that these node will be categorized in called "sections". I need a way to make all current nodes with "categories/term-1" to also have "sections/term-1", "categories/term-2" to have "sections/term-2", and so on. I was thinking I could do this with rules, but that would be a per node basis and I need this to update ALL current nodes. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) to update multiple nodes at once with a single run of update.php. Inside it you can load all the nodes that you need to modify using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7), and after you are done changing the taxonomies programatically, call [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7).

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how to do this? How would I use node_load() to load all nodes tagged with a term? Thanks.

Comment: First you would need to come up with a database query that will return all the nodes that you want to alter. One trick I often employ is to use Views to come up with the query for you, and then copy/paste/modify it to your needs. For documentation on database queries you can consult these links: [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), [Database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7), [db queries](http://drupal.org/node/310072). But you can also google further information.

Comment: The purpose of that database query will be returning just the nids of the nodes that you want to alter. You can do a loop with the database results, and within the loop call `$node_obj = node_load($nid);`. Once you load the node you might want to try using [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) to get and alter the taxonomy field, but you could end up altering the taxonomy in another way. Once you modify the taxonomy field, then call node_save() on the node.

Comment: For examples on how to implement hook_update_N() just look at the .install file of any contributed module. Contrib code will often provide a better example than the code we could come up with here. Also the original link to the hook in the question is helpful.